# Using Celery, how do I post rabbitmq messages to another docker container?

Tags: python, django, docker, rabbitmq, celery

It appears my celery workers launch and connect properly on the mymachine.domain.com:port where the rabbit mq resides in a separate docker container.

However when I call the function apply_async from my web application it tries to connect on localhost:port even though it should be using the same django src/settings.py file which would also be mymachine.domain.com:port again.

The only way I can get this to work is by setting the docker network_mode to 'host'. This is not an acceptable mode though for security reasons.

Here is my celery.py file:

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','src.settings')

import django
django.setup()

from src.apps.main.tasks import cleanup, syncldap 

app = Celery('myappcelery', backend='amqp',
# Expected  next line isn't even used because line with 'django.conf:settings' will override it with the config settings.

broker='amqp://user@mymachine.domain.com:5672//',                          include=['src.apps.appname.tasks'])
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', 
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Here is my src.settings.py file settings:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://user:password@mymachine.domain.com:5672//'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'

CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'celery'
```

I added a print statement to the following installed file file:
site-packages/kombu/connection.py

In the function:

```
def default_channel(self):
```

I added this print statement:

```
print "Connection %s" % self.connect
```

From my celery workers I see this in the logs:

```
Connection <bound method Connection.connect of <Connection: amqp://<user>:**@mymachine.domain.com:5672// at 0x7fd1e3700450>>
```

But when I try to call apply_async I see the following message and it just hangs:

```
Connection <bound method Connection.connect of <Connection: amqp://<user>:**@localhost:5672// at 0x7fc01371bc50>>
```

Where localhost is the web application's docker container and will not properly connect to rabbit mq located on the host machine.  This explains why in host mode it works because then localhost:5672 is the same for rabbitmq and the web container. But in bridge mode, you cannot get to the host using localhost, that is why I specify the hostname in the configs. I am not sure why this is getting overwritten back to localhost.

Also FYI when I ran the celery workers it was from the same machine with the same config files, and yet the print statement I added showed the correct host.

Comment: FYI I am using celery (4.1.0), amqp (2.2.1), Django (1.11), django-celery (3.2.1) and kombu (4.1.0)

Comment: Another observation I had. Any tasks called from that celery.py file have the correct host as well. But if they are called from the autodiscover_tasks from a task.py in the web site with decorators, it doesn't appear to pull the config settings for the broker.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I needed to instantiate app in my tasks.py file as well.

Before

```
@task(name='func_name', bind=True)
def func_name(self, id)
```

After

```
app = Celery('celery', backend='amqp',
             broker='amqp://user@mymachine.domain.com:5672//')
@app.task(name='func_name', bind=True)
def func_name(self, id)
```

When these were imported into celery.py from the function autodiscover_tasks it loaded the app config. But when loaded from the web there was no reference to config until I added it, so it was using the default localhost.